# Adding fully connected layers after pretrained model

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I'm new to ConvNets and Python and want to implement the following:

I want to use the pretrained vgg16 model and add 3 fully connected layers after it with an L2-Normalization at the end.

> So Data->VGG16->FC (1x4096)->FC (1x4096)->FC (1x3)->L2-Norm->Output

The first and second FC get an array 1x4096 the last FC gets an array 1x3 where the L2-Norm is performed.

Can anyone give me a hint how to do that ?

I found that I can load the model like that :

> model_vgg19 = models.vgg19(pretrained=True)

But how can I add the FCs and the L2-Norm after that ? And how can I get Test-Data through the model ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting an example mentioned in [Keras#3465](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3465)

In Keras framework, if you mention `include_top = False` while loading your pre-trained model it will not include the final classification layer. You can add your custom FC layers at the end as shown in the example below:

```
#load vgg16 without dense layer and with theano dim ordering
base_model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False, input_shape = (3,224,224))

#number of classes in your dataset e.g. 20
num_classes = 20

x = Flatten()(base_model.output)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax')(x)

#create graph of your new model
head_model = Model(input = base_model.input, output = predictions)

#compile the model
head_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

head_model.summary()
.
.
.
#train your model on data
head_model.fit(x, y, batch_size = batch_size, verbose = 1)
```